# Publish Post when URL is available else reschedule the post in wordpress

Tags: urls, publish

Following are the steps which I want to achieve
**1**. I will schedule a post. (Cron Job will setup)
**2**. When that scheduled post is about to publish then URL (which i will provide) will be checked,

If URL is available then post will be published successfully
Else post will be rescheduled to repeat the full process after 15 mins.

**In Short:**
My post will be published when my provided URL (Return HTTP:200) will be available else post will keep rescheduling.

Comment: Waiting anyone to help init